# Using *ngIf to Handle Active vs Inactive Flags Being Printed to View in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

In the template of my Angular 2 app I am handling printing flags to the screen. Because this is Angular 2 (not Angular 4) - and we're not ready to move to Angular 4 yet, I'm not able to define an "else" block, so I have to find a different way to accomplish what would be simple with an "else" block.

Right now I am printing flags to the column of this table data if there are flags where "completed === false" -- meaning they are active.

Where I'm running into a challenge is in how to handle a situation where there either are no flags, or there are, but the property "completed" for that object is set to "true" -- so in that case they are no longer active flags.

Basically I want to use *ngFor and *ngIf to print flags to the column when there are flags, and the "completed" property is set to "false" for those flags. And if there either are no flags, or all flags found have the "completed" property set to "true", I just want to print "Clear" to the screen. This is what I have so far:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let service of record.services"> 

        <ng-template *ngIf="service?.service === 'consulting services' && service?.flags">
            <ng-template *ngFor="let flag of service.flags">
                <span *ngIf="flag?.completed === false" class="standard-flag" 
                    [class.hold-flag]="flag?.flagType === 'hold'">Flag
                </span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template *ngFor="let flag of service.flags">
                <span *ngIf="flag?.completed === true" class="green-flag">Clear
                </span>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>

    </ng-container>
```

Right now what this is producing is both kinds of flags are being printed to the screen (where "completed" is either "false" or "true"). What I want to do is say something like -- if there are no flags, or there are flags, but "completed === true" for all of them, ONLY then print "Clear" to the screen.

That way there's always something in the column - either "Flag" or "Clear" -- but it should never be both in the same column. Hope that's clear.

What kind of syntactical construction could I use here in the view to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [ngSwitch](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchCase-directive.html).

It's like a switch statement just handled in templating.  You might have to create another variable to control the switch statement.  Hopefully you can handle that logic, as I'm just passing along the syntactic construct it seems you might be looking for.

Comment: Does ngSwitch exist in Angular 2, or is that just AngularJS?

Comment: Yeah it does, sorry I linked to the wrong docs, I'll fix my answer, but I'm using it in my project

Comment: Cool. That may be exactly what I need. Will check it out, thanks.